# Related Tables LINQ statement / EF 6 - One to Many, Most recent record

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to return some data from 2 related tables. I have a one to many relationship.  One `WebLead` can have many `Pricing` records.  I would like to return the data for the `WebLead` and the data for most recent record inserted into the `Pricing` table.

I am new to LINQ and EF.  Here is what I have so far but this is only returning the `WebLeads` table data...What am I missing? Do I need to add a `FirstOrDefault` for the `Pricing` table?

```
 var priceRefi = db.WebLeads.Include(p => p.Pricings)
.Where(l => l.LoanAgent.Equals(LoanAgent) && l.LeadStatus.Equals("Priced");
```

then to populate the view model:

```
PricedRefiLeads = priceRefi.ToList(),
```

UPDATE: I am sorry I left so much out.  I updated my query to the following (`LoanAgent` is just a `string` parameter)

```
var priceRefi = from lead in db.WebLeads
                        where lead.LoanAgent == LoanAgent && lead.LeadStatus == "Priced"
                        select new LeadWithLastPricing()
                        {
                            Lead = lead,
                            LastPricing = lead.Pricings.OrderByDescending(x => x.PricingDate).FirstOrDefault()
                        };
```

I then want to take the results of that query and return it as a list to my view model:

```
var viewModel = new PipelineViewModel
{                
    ////  
    PricedRefiLeads = priceRefi.ToList(),
}
```

I am seeing the following error on the `priceRefi.ToList()`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(LoanModule.ViewModels.LeadWithLastPricing)'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(LoanModule.Models.WebLead)

I am new to MVC.  As I read this error, I understand that I must be missing something in my `PipelineViewModel` but I am not sure what that is.

In `PipelineViewModel`, I do have:

```
public List<WebLead> PricedRefiLeads { get; set; }
```

What am I missing?  Forgive me if I left information out, I am struggling to wrap my head around this.

Comment: you shouldn't do `Equals()` to compare objects in the database, you should compare their primary keys.

Comment: I am using the equals to filter out records. I only want records of a certain type, but I want the data for that record from both tables....

Comment: @Daniela, But `WebLead` does not contain a field for `LastPricing`, so you will need to change `List<WebLead> PricedRefiLeads { get; set; }` to `List<LeadWithLastPricing> PricedRefiLeads { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a number of assumptions, for information not specifically mentioned in your question:

- `LoanAgent` is a (local) string variable representing the agent you want to filter on.
- `Pricing` has a field named `PricingDate` that is of type `DateTime`.

Then you can do it like this:

```
// I am assuming a Pricing has a DateTime field named "PricingDate"
var priceRefi = 
    from lead in WebLeads
    where lead.LoanAgent == LoanAgent && lead.LeadStatus == "Priced"
    select new {
        Lead = lead,
        LastPricing = lead.Pricings.OrderByDescending(x => x.PricingDate).FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

Note that this returns an anonymous object as the projection result. If you want to pass this result on, you should create a class:

```
public class LeadWithLastPricing
{
    public Lead Lead { get; set; }
    public Pricing LastPricing { get; set; }
}
```

And do the `select` part like this:

```
    // ...
    select new LeadWithLastPricing() {
        Lead = lead,
        LastPricing = lead.Pricings.OrderByDescending(x => x.PricingDate).FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

For your second error, change this:

```
public List<WebLead> PricedRefiLeads { get; set; }
```

To

```
public List<LeadWithLastPricing> PricedRefiLeads { get; set; }
```

And use it like:

```
var viewModel = new PipelineViewModel
{                
    PricedRefiLeads = priceRefi.ToList(),
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I left so much out without realizing it.  I have this now (loan agent is actually just parameter passed a querystring.                        var priceRefi = from lead in db.WebLeads
                            where lead.LoanAgent == LoanAgent && lead.LeadStatus == "Priced"
                            select new LeadWithLastPricing()
                            {
                                Lead = lead,
                                LastPricing = lead.Pricings.OrderByDescending(x => x.PricingDate).FirstOrDefault()
                            };

Comment: @Daniela, could you then please add the information, that resolves these assumptions to your question: i.e. (1) add information on LoanAgent` being a string (2) Add that you want the `Pricing` with the most recent value for 'PricingDate`.

Comment: At this point, there are 6 blank rows all with an ID of 0 in my table. Based on the query filters, there should only be 3 rows...

Comment: @Daniela. Yes, you will need to refer to `item.Lead.LeadID` and `item.LastPricing.PricingDate`, using the specific properties you need for your view,

Comment: Thank you Alex!  I really learned a lot from your answer - you connected a lot of dots for me with MVC.  Thank for your patience with my newbie self!

Comment: @Daniela You didn't need to create a brand new class.  If you are using POCO classes, you can just project into a Lead, but you'd need to copy over all the properties.  Just change the .Select portion to `.Select(lead=>new WebLead { lead.LoanAgent,lead.LeadStatus,...,Pricing=lead.Pricings.OrderByDescending(x=>x.PricingDate).Take(1)}` and unless your viewModel contains more than just the Leads, you can just use `IEnumerable<WebLead>` as your viewModel and save yourself another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
   var query =
            from l in db.WebLeads
            let maxDate = l.Pricings.Max(p => p.InsertDate)
            where l.LoanAgentID == someLoanAgentID
            && l.LeadStatus == "Priced"
            select new { Lead = l, Pricing = l.Pricings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InsertDate == maxDate) };
```

This will give objects with two properties: Lead and Pricing which are WebLead and Pricings objects.  Please forgive syntax errors this is streight out of notepad.

Edit:  I suppose I should tell you how to use the result object:

```
foreach (var MyLead in query)
{
   string customerName = MyLead.Lead.CustomerName; // i.e. some property of WebLead
   DateTime InsertDate = MyLead.Pricing.InsertDate; // i.e. some property of Pricings

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can project directly into a WebLead instead of creating a new class, by doing the following:

```
var priceRefi = db.WebLeads
  .Include(p => p.Pricings)
  .Where(l => l.LoanAgent == LoanAgent)
  .Where(l => l.LeadStatus == "Priced")
  .Select(lead=>new WebLead {
    lead.LoanAgent,
    lead.LeadStatus,
    ...,
    Pricings=lead.Pricings.OrderByDescending(x=>x.‌​PricingDate).Take(1)});
```

Comment: This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.